# Can't run Xamarin UI Tests in Cloud for Android 6.0 devices

Tags: android, ruby, xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

In my Xamarin project I have UI Tests that works on all my local devices (also with Android 4.0, 5.0 and 6.0), but unfortunately when I run them in Xamarin Test Cloud they fail always only for Android 6.0 version.

This is the error:

> 1) SetUp Error :
>   App.UITests.Droid.Tests.BuildTest(Android).Check_Build
>   SetUp : System.Exception : App installation failed with output:
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc8e043c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:751:in
>   `connect': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc8e043c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:613:in`
>   query': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc84322c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:875:in
>   `parse_header': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout
>   instead.
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc8e0022c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:986:in`
>   read_body_chunked': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout
>   instead. Failure. Expected Package Name: XXX. Adb
>   Packages Output:
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc8e0342c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/adt/sdk/platform-tools/adb:402:
>   warning: already initialized constant ARGV
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc343c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:751:in
>   `connect': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc43022c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:613:in`
>   query': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout instead.
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc84322c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:875:in
>   `parse_header': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout
>   instead.
>   /Volumes/Data/xamarin/pipeline/versions/7ddfc432c82182471a14f3136c778635e1620/base_gems/gems/httpclient-2.3.4.1/lib/httpclient/session.rb:986:in`
>   read_body_chunked': Object#timeout is deprecated, use Timeout.timeout
>   instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a problem with permissions. You have to grant permission first.

From the Xamarin Test Page:

> When the IDE installs an Android 6.0 app for the first time, it does not grant all permissions required by the application. The workaround for this is to use UITest to install and start the application:

```
ConfigureApp.Android.Debug().ApkFile(apkpath).StartApp ()
```

[Link to the Xamarin.UITest Cheat Sheet # Android 6.0 page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/testcloud/uitest/cheatsheet/#Running_Android_6.0_Applications_from_the_IDE)